# Rails: working on temporary instance between requests and then commit changes to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have already read [Rails - How do I temporarily store a rails model instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791957/rails-how-do-i-temporarily-store-a-rails-model-instance) and similar questions but I cannot find a successful answer.

Imagine I have the model `Customer`, which may contain a huge amount of information attached (simple attributes, data in other tables through `has_many` relation, etc...). I want the application's user to access all data in a single page with a single `Save` button on it. As the user makes changes in the data (i.e. he changes simple attributes, adds or deletes `has_many` items,...) I want the application to update the model, but **without committing changes to the database**. Only when the user clicks on `Save`, the model must be committed.

For achieving this I need the model to be kept by Rails between HTTP requests. Furthermore, two different users may be changing the model's data at the same time, so these temporary instances should be bound to the Rails session.

Is there any way to achieve this? Is it actually a good idea? And, if not, how can one design a web application in which changes in a model cannot be retained in the browser but in the server until the user wants to commit them?

**EDIT**

Based on user *smallbutton.com*'s proposal, I wonder if [serializing the model instance to a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310217/how-can-i-save-an-object-to-a-file) (whose path would be stored in the `session` hash), and then reloading it each time a new request arrives, would do the trick. Would it work in all cases? Is there any piece of information that would be lost during serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

As HTTP requests are stateless you need some kind of storeage between requests. The session is the easiest way to store data between requests. As for you the session will not be enough because you need it to be accessed by multiple users.

I see two ways to achive your goal:

1) Get some fast external data storage like a key-value server (redis, or anything you prefer http://nosql-database.org/) where you put your objects via serializing/deserializing (eg. JSON). 
This may be fast depending on your design choices and data model but this is the harder approach.

2) Just store your Objects in the DB as you would regularly do and get them versioned: (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). Then you can just store a timestamp when people hit the save-button and you can always go back to this state. This would be the easier approach i guess but may be a bit slower depending on the size of your data model changes ( but I think it'll do )

EDIT: If you need real-time collaboration between users you should probably have a look at something like Firebase

**EDIT2: Anwer to your second question, whether you can put the data into a file:**

Sure you can do that. But you would need some kind of locking to prevent data loss if more than one person is editing. You will need that aswell if you go for 1) but tools like redis already include  locks to achive your goal (eg. redis-semaphore). Depending on your data you may need to build some logic for merging different changes of different users.

3) Another aproach that came to my mind would be doing all editing with Javascript and save it in one db-transaction. This would go well with synchronization tools like firebase (or your own synchronization via Rails streaming API)