# Preserve form data on Rails post without an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am aware that you can save form data using an instance variable, but what is the recommended mechanism to use for doing the same thing without one ? I have a case where I need to create a form that is not backed by a model and i need to preserve form data across posting the form.

I am thinking of going with local storage or a cookie, but is there maybe some better way or a gem that handles this already?

Thanks!

Comment: Storing data structures in a cookie is bad practice. Cookies need to be as simple as possible. I would use ActiveResource or just a plain old Ruby Object but you are posting data in order to save it so it can be used somewhere else right? So why not create a table and use ActiveRecord? You of course have the option of using other persistent data stores.  YAML might be a good fit but it's impossible to help with so little info to go on

Comment: I kinda wanted to avoid creating a model because it creates an entity that doesn't make a lot of sense for the project. This is not a data structure really, it's just some integers that I want to save and retrieve for the respective form fields.

Comment: @Spyros please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5792014/14475852)

Comment: That is exactly the purpose of storing data, just so it can be reused somewhere. Perhaps you are overthinking this? Just generate a new model with the fields you want to persist, it's not an anti pattern. Just do it! lol

Comment: The Rails way to store small pieces of information between two requests seems to be the [`flash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) storage.

Comment: Another way might be to simply store the data in query parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments guys ! I ended up going with local storage and it seems to be working just fine :)

Comment: "I am aware that you can save form data using an instance variable". Instance variables don't really have anything to do with storing anything across requests. Its a basic building block of the language thats used to encapsulate variables in objects. Sure when you build a system that stores data across requests you're going to use instance variables but its like saying "I heard this classes thing can be used to build applications".

Comment: Have you had a look at hotwire and turbo streams and turbo frames? They might just be a modern solution to your issue https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails

Comment: @max Thanks for the condescending lesson, I knew all that already. You can still use them to save form data across requests.

Comment: @jamesc looks interesting, wasn't aware no! I will take closer, look, thanks!